# Implied Volatility - Underlying vs Monthly Expiration vs Individual Options

Tags: options, implied-volatility

I'm working on calculating implied volatility for historical options data taken from the [tradier api](https://documentation.tradier.com/brokerage-api). I'm using Davis Edwards fantastic python implementation of options pricing models to get individual implied volatility and greeks calculations for individual options, but am trying to understand how to get the monthly expiration IV and IV of the underlying.

For example, looking at the AMD chain in thinkorswim, we see that the underlying has an implied volatility of 59.06% (pink), the monthly's each have an implied volatility (yellow) and the 5Feb21 84.5 call has an implied volatility of 52.06% (cyan).

I understand how the individual options implied volatility is calculated, but how do I aggregate these to get the monthly and overall implied vol?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Generally, you would need to ask them for their documentation. Usually, the underlying has no IV, if you ever see sich values, it's a VIX like measure. The same applies to the different tent vols.